# ¿Porque este bucle while que aplique hice no suma correctamente los numeros ingresados en un prompt en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, while, prompt

Es un ejercicio que he estado resolviendo, por como ven no es tan complejo o eso es lo que parece, la logica es hacer una variable contador de la cantidad de numeros, una variable para almacenarlos y hacer la suma, por ultimo la variable que declaro para ingresarlos por prompt, cabe aclarar que use parseint y Number pero creo que ese no es el problema.

la cuestion aqui es que tengo que ingresar numeros por prompt hasta que ingrese un numero negativo y termina el bucle , los suma y luego saca el promedio.

mi problema es que ingreso por ejemplo 1 + 1 + 1 luego ingreso negativo -1 para terminar el proceso y en lugar de devolver 3 devuelve 0 y asi con otros intentos con otros numeros salen respuestas que nada que ver.
este es mi codigo:

```js
let n = Number(prompt('Ingresa un numero: '));

let i = 0; //cantidad de numeros

let x = 0; //acumulador de valor para suma




while (n > 0) {

       n = Number(prompt('Ingresa un numero: '));

       //i = i + 1;

       x = x + n;


}

   


console.log(`La suma es igual a ${x}`);
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Esto no es programación bajo nivel, jejeje

Comment: gracias por la aclaracion , si es alto nivel aqui me mande una, recien empiezo en esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues no le sumes el número cuando no sea mayor que cero. Ten en cuenta que la validación del while la haces con el valor que estás recibiendo **en la iteración anterior**.

Ej:

```
Arrancas fuera del while
Pides un número **y no se lo sumas a X**
n <-- 1

Entras al while
n > 0 ? Sí (es 1)
Pides un número
n <-- 2
x = 0 + 2 = 2

Iteras de nuevo
n > 0 ? Sí (es 2)
Pides un número
n <-- 3
x = 2 + 3 = 5

Iteras de nuevo
n > 0 ? Sí (es 3)
Pides un número
n <-- -1
x = 5 + (-1) = 4

Iteras de nuevo
n > 0 ? No (es -1)

Sales del while

Imprimes 4
```

Podrías iniciar con n = 1 o usar un do-while o algo para que la primera iteración no sea rara, y valida que si la condición se cumple, no se sume el valor de salida

```js
let n = 1;
let i = 0; //cantidad de numeros
let x = 0; //acumulador de valor para suma

while (n > 0) {
    // Igual sobreescribes n acá, no importa iniciarlo en 1
    n = Number(prompt('Ingresa un numero: '));

    if (n > 0) {
        x = x + n;
    }
}

console.log(`La suma es igual a ${x}`);
```

Comment: Ya lo consegui resolver gracias a tu respuesta sin embargo usando numeros altos mientras más alto es el promedio suele no ser exacto al de la calculadora pero la diferencia es de 20 unidades cuando pasa de 1000

Comment: @yeikyu en tu pregunta no hablas de promedios ni nada parecido. Si tienes _otra_ duda, abre otra pregunta, por favor. Si lo que preguntaste se resolvió, recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así otros sabrán que lo resolviste usando esto

Comment: como hgo para marcar como aceptada la respuesta